# How to insert a ICollection<string> into one Field in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have ICollection object in my controller. This collection posted from view like this;

`{string[3]}`

`[0]=a`

`[1]=b`

`[2]=c`

```
        public ActionResult TarifEkle(Tarifler tarif, ICollection<string> tAdim)
     {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Tarif"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "insert into [NePisirsem].[dbo].[Tarifler](tAdim) values (@builder)";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
```

I change this value like this a,b,c with my builder;

```
         var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (string item in tAdim)
        {
          builder.Append(item).Append(",");
             sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@builder", tarif.tAdim);
        }
```

It works values are successfully became i want `(a,b,c)` but I can't add this values this way `a,b,c`
 `sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@builder", tarif.tAdim);` this code takes always just first value `a` not all of them.

How can i do?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is used to build strings, it's not a value itself. If you want to join all strings in the `tAdim` collection use `String.Join`

Comment: you can serialize   as XML format or binary format, then save it in your database.I think it is best first encode by `builder.ToString()` and save it in Database,  then decode it from Database and use in your application

Comment: Why not just persist `builder.ToString()` as a single string value?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Write *one* comma-separated string with IDs to a single row in the table? Write *multiple* rows, one per ID? SqlBuilder isn't needed for any of them

Comment: i am trying to merge values posting from different textarea,with comma @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @CelalBahadırKAYA did you try `String.Join(",",tAdim)` to generate the comma-separated string?

Comment: String.Join(",",tAdim) does not work. I'm just having trouble saving  @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: String.Join works. Your code though has serious issues - you can't assign the same parameter multiple times. The code never uses the string builder.

Comment: I don't have trouble to merge values.(String.Join and builder did same thing ) I'm just can't save merged values. sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@builder", tarif.tAdim);  it's always takes first item @Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you.

Comment: If im not horribly mistaken, writing `"@builder"` doesn't automatically use your `var builder` from your code. `AddWithValue("@builder", tarif.tAdim)` Your code sets `tarif.tAdim` as value for `@builder` So whatever is in `tarif.tAdim` will be written to the DB. Please check out my answer and read carefully through the references. Im sure it will help you understand.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer without ego @LuckyLikey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need tho change the following section

```
     var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (string item in tAdim)
    {
      builder.Append(item).Append(",");
         sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@builder", tarif.tAdim);
    }
```

to

```
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@builder", string.Join(",", tAdim));
```

`@builder` will then be replaced by `a,b,c` in your `sqlquery` if you need `a, b, c` replace `","` with `", "`. Read more about `string.Join()` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-join-method-set-2/).

#### Don't use `AddWithValue()`

As you can read [here](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), you should prefere `Parameters.Add()` over `Parameters.AddWithValue()` as you can specify the appropriate [SqlDbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.7.2) that your string is converted to.

```
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@builder", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = string.Join(",", tAdim);
```

Either use `SqlDbType.VarChar` or `SqlDbType.NVarChar` and replace `30` with your actual max lenght.

---

#### INSERT INTO Statement

As explained [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/), the format of an insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

`column_list` is a list of Columns that in your case are on `[NePisirsem].[dbo].[Tarifler]` e.g. `tAdim`. Then multiple `value_lists` can be supplied, each generating a new row in your table. `value_list` needs to match the order of `column_list`

Comment: I have multiple textarea fields in my view. It can 3 or 4 or much more it depends user, i want to merge with comma all values posted from different textarea and save one column in my table

Comment: So you need a string `"a, b, c"` to be in one row in the column `tAdim`?

Comment: Yes,a b c is sent separately I just need to merge them(a,b,c) and save into one column.I'm just having trouble saving no problem with other codes

Comment: ah good to hear. You mind give me credits for it, by accept it as answer and maybe upvote? Have a nice day :)

Comment: :) I already tried but my reputation less than 15 ,my vote saved but doesn't share to other :) have a nice day too

Comment: never mind. What I meant was that you can signal that this answer solved your question by marking it as an answer. It's also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)